# C# Socket Read/Write performance

Tags: c#, sockets, tcplistener

I'm developing a gaming TCP server and I'm planning that it should withstand up to about 500 connections. Data transfer occurs constantly (movement of the character, attack, etc.).

I started develop with the **TCPListener**, but I got a performance problem.
I used await **XXXSync** methods to accept clients, receive data, and sending messages.

I created a program that simulates the actions of players. It allowed to create only 30-40 connections and this caused 100% of the CPU. To test my server, I used two machines: one was a simulator of players, on the other - a server.
These **30-40 clients** load the **CPU** on the server **by 10-20%** and very much (at 100%) while simultaneously disconnecting all TCP clients.

I was looking for information about optimizing the TCPListener, but nothing found. I've seen topics where people have written that they own a server with 1,000+ connections and this works well.

I thought that the reason could be in the logic of my server, but the profiling tools showed that the main part of the CPU load is getting and sending data (await client.ReadAsync / client.WriteAsync).
[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baznQ.png) | [Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YidL6.png)

---

I started looking for possible alternatives and found **SocketAsyncEventArgs**. At the forum, people wrote that this method can increase productivity by 2 times. I found the source codes of some servers written in C # and took from there the implementation of SocketAsyncEventArgs.

This really greatly increased the productivity by 10-15 times. For 30 simulations, this causes now only 0.5-2%.

I rewrote the emulator of the players at SocketAsyncEventArgs and this allowed me to create 100 simulations with 20% CPU.

After 70 players the load on the CPU on the server grew and is 7-13%.
Profiling tools show that the main use of the CPU is the sending of messages.
For some reason, the most productive option for me was BeginWrite. Write was not suitable because it blocks the stream. WriteAsync was slower, or I just misused it. [Picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjpdN.png) | [Picture 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIGDx.png)

I can not find information about optimizing Sockets on c #. Everyone everywhere writes that they are all well even on the TCPListener, which for me is simply unbearable.

**Is there any other way to improve performance?**

---

P.S. I tested the server on a computer with i7 seventh generation.

Comment: Please post the code as code alongside the profiling screenshots

Comment: https://ibb.co/iaYq58
https://ibb.co/kLGhJT
There are screenshot of receiving clients and messages

Comment: Again, please post the actual *code*

Comment: Writing a server that simply accepts _"1000"_ connections and writing a _multiplayer game of 1000 players_ are two completely different things.  The latter is incredibility difficult and simply using a TCP listener on a single computer is most likely not the way to do it

Comment: You're ignoring the Async return values, which means you're leaking resources left and right.  That's probably not good for performance.  Ok, your version with the AsyncEventArgs seems to be better in that regard.

Comment: Which "Async return values" you mean?